# link color is stuck on active (blue)

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

Hihi,

I have a problem with three links in the same div... the ugly default blue link color is blocking the assigned font-color to take over

URL: http://nicejob.is/clients/pizzahollin/www/menu.htm

Any help would be nice - typical it´s just a typo but I´ve tried everything

Answer (score 1):

At least from what I can see, you don't have any defaults set for `a`, which would be why the browser is handling it.

And if you're expecting this to, then yes, you have a typo in main.css

```
.font-filer a { color:#997f62; }
```

needs to be

```
.font-filter a { color:#997f62; }
```

Comment: typical it was just a typo - thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

You set the font-color on the surrounding `p` but not on the `a` itself. Try explicitly setting a color for the link.

```
<!-- In the stylesheet, you set explicit color for p -->
<p class="font-filter"> 
    <!-- and not for a, so it's using default -->
    <a title="most-popular" href="#most-popular"> 
        <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Vinsælustu" style="width: 145px; height: 34px;">
            <canvas width="158" height="36" style="width: 158px; height: 36px; top: -2px; left: -1px;"></canvas>
            <cufontext>Vinsælustu</cufontext>
        </cufon>
    </a>
</p>
```

Comment: so the tag "cufontext" is recommended when using cufon replacement?